# Create 1 Email Per Unique Recipient from Excel with Lists of Names

Tags: excel, vba, list, outlook

I have updated my code per advice from others, shown below.  I have the below code and it works, nearly perfectly.  Please see the sample data.  The code goes down the names in Column A and creates an email for each unique name, placing the corresponding names in column E as a list.  It goes on to the next unique name in A until done.

My issue now is that when the code runs, when it gets to the end, or a blank in the name column 1, it creates an error.  I want it to just stop instead.  I have highlighted the line where it shows the error in break mode.

Please help me correct this so that it knows to stop when it reaches the bottom.  So, when it gets to the bottom of the list at Shirt,Gray, it tries to go to the next line but since it is blank, it errors out.  I just need it to stop without an error.

Thank you.

```
Sub TEST3()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim strname As String
    Dim strname1 As String
    Dim strname2 As String
    Dim strEmp As String
    Dim previousName As String
    Dim nextName As String

    Dim emailWS As Worksheet
    Dim nameCol As Double
    Dim nameCol2 As Double
    Dim empCol As Double
    Dim lastCol As Double
    Dim lastRow As Double
    Dim startRow As Double
    Dim startCol As Double
    Dim r As Double
    
    Dim empList As String
    
    
    sigstring = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\work.htm"
                              
        If Dir(sigstring) <> "" Then
         signature = GetBoiler(sigstring)
         Else
         signature = ""
        End If

    empList = ""
    previousName = ""
    nextName = ""

    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Set emailWS = ActiveSheet
    startRow = 2
    startCol = 1
    nameCol = 3
    nameCol2 = 1
    empCol = 6
   
    lastRow = emailWS.Cells(emailWS.Rows.Count, nameCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    lastCol = emailWS.Cells(1, emailWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For r = startRow To lastRow
        
        strname = (emailWS.Cells(r, nameCol2))
        strname1 = Trim(Split(emailWS.Cells(r, nameCol2), ",")(1))
        
        strEmp = emailWS.Cells(r, empCol)

      
        If emailWS.Cells(r + 1, nameCol2) <> "" Then
          
           nextName = (emailWS.Cells(r + 1, nameCol2))
        Else
           
           nextName = "Exit"
        End If

        If strname <> previousName Then
            
            previousName = strname
           
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            
            With OutMail
             
               .To = emailWS.Cells(r, 2).Value
               .Subject = "Low Balance "
                empList = strEmp & "<br>"
                
                strbody = "<Font Face=calibri>Dear " & strname1 & ", <br><br> As of the last week, the below have a low balance. "

            End With
        Else
    
    If InStr(empList, strEmp) = 0 Then
        
        empList = empList & strEmp & "<br>"
    Else
        
    End If


       If strname <> nextName Then
            
            OutMail.HTMLBody = strbody & "<B>" & empList & "</B>" & "<br>" & signature
            OutMail.Display
        Else
        End If
    End If
    Next r

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing


    End Sub

    Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    End Function
```

[image: Sample Data]

Edit:  this is the error I get, and below that is the line of code it stops at.  I get why it is erroring out, but do not know how to fix it/make it stop.

[image: Error]

[image: Line of code]

Comment: the unique names are in column E? your attached pic says otherwise, you should be more specific, for each unique name what data does it get to add into the email?

Comment: Hi @k1dr0ck, thanks, but I am not sure what you mean about the column...the names are in column E.  That is the key item that the code looks at and then pulls in the names from column A.  It is only adding in the names from column A as a list..."these people below are at a low balance/over."

Comment: Nevermind @k1dr0ck, I see what you mean.  I fixed it.

Comment: Hi @k1dr0ck, I have updated my code, revised it...please see the question now.  Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest posting new questions to new threads at SO, so users could recognize questions and answers easily.

Comment: I posted it as a new question.  Please help if you have an answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is the error I get when I set it to send instead of display. It only sends the first 3 emails, with the 3rd only including the first name.

The number of `CreateItem` calls doesn't correspond to the number of `Display` or `Send` calls in the code:

```
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

You need to review your code to avoid such issues.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I am a novice...how do I do that/fix it?  Just add a number?

Comment: Just keep `CreateItem` and `Display`/`Send` under the same condition.

Comment: lol...talk to me like I am 3...how do I do that?  what condition?  again, my apologies, and thank you!!

Comment: You need to re-build the structure of your code where you create a new mail item and call the `Send` method in the same block of code (for example, inside the same `If` block)

Comment: Hi, so I have re-worked my code but still having the same issue.  Please see my update above.  Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest posting new questions to new threads at SO, so users could recognize questions and answers easily.

Answer (score 0):

still confused at your explanation and the shown data pic

try

```
strname = (emailWS.Cells(r, nameCol2))
If emailWS.Cells(r, nameCol2) = "" then Exit Sub
strname1 = Trim(Split(emailWS.Cells(r, nameCol2), ",")(1))
```